# VBA Formatting issue causing compile errors

Tags: excel, vba, format

I am currently trying to format a block of code someone gave me in a comment on a previous question but have been getting a lot of compile errors.

The question this answers was posted yesterday and closed for some reason.  It's titled: Visual basic macro for excel that inserts rows based on quantity of product column [closed]

The code:

```
Sub ExpandRows()

Dim lastRow As Long
Dim i As Long
Dim qty As Long
Dim productType As String
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Worksheets("Sheet1")
'Insert here your worksheet name
' Assuming data starts from row 2
lastRow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
' Loop through each row
For i = lastRow To 2 Step -1
qty = ws.Cells(i, 1).Value
productType = ws.Cells(i, 2).Value
' Insert rows and fill with product type
If qty > 1 Then Rows(i + 1 & ":" & i + qty - 1).Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
Range(Cells(i, 2), Cells(i + qty - 1, 2)).Value = productType
End If
Next i


End Sub
```

I am not sure where to insert line breaks in the end of this.
The code is supposed to insert rows under products that have a quantity more than one then copy down the descriptions of the product to fill the columns in the inserted rows.

Thanks for any help!

I have tried breaking the lines at the bottom up in multiple ways and am just causing more and more compile errors and am not very familiar with VBA formatting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Transform data with an array is more efficient.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub Demo()
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, k As Long
    Dim arrData, rngData As Range, arrRes
    arrData = ActiveSheet.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Value
    ReDim arrRes(1 To Application.Sum(Range("a:a")), 1 To UBound(arrData, 2))
    k = 1
    For i = LBound(arrData) + 1 To UBound(arrData)
        For j = 1 To arrData(i, 1)
            If j = 1 Then arrRes(k, 1) = arrData(i, 1)
            arrRes(k, 2) = arrData(i, 2)
            k = k + 1
        Next j
    Next i
    Range("A2").Resize(k - 1, 2).Value = arrRes
End Sub
```

[image]

*Microsoft documentation:*

> [Range.CurrentRegion property (Excel)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.currentregion?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-33461&f1url=%3FappId%3DDev11IDEF1%26l%3Den-US%26k%3Dk(vbaxl10.chm144111)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-Office.Version%3Dv16)%26rd%3Dtrue)

> [Range.Resize property (Excel)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.resize?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-33461)

---

btw, your code should be revised as below.

```
        If qty > 1 Then
            Rows(i + 1 & ":" & i + qty - 1).Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
            Range(Cells(i, 2), Cells(i + qty - 1, 2)).Value = productType
        End If
```

Comment: I am getting an error after going through the use cases of this Excel sheet.

The quantities that are put into column M are the second column of data pasted in the selection from another sheet.
There are product identifiers like this: "149901-66" in column N, quantities in M, then descriptions in O.  If the N column is left blank for stock product the macro works fine but if col. N has the special product identifiers included I get a Runtime error: 13 "Type mismatch" error.  I have tested it after deleting the data from col. N and it works again.

Comment: I would suggest you create a new post to share the sample data and your revised code.  https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266767/what-is-the-the-best-way-to-ask-follow-up-questions  Which line raises `Runtime error: 13`?

Comment: I have to wait another 30 minutes before I can post another question.  I had another one closed an hour ago an I can only ask 1 every 90 minutes.

Comment: Editing the current post to include the detail is helpful to understand your issue.

Comment: The error coming from ```For j = 1 To arrData(i, 1)```

Comment: If arrData(i, 1)  is not a number, it raises error 13. You have to revise the code accordingly if you change the data layout.

Comment: The only thing I changed about the code in the answer is ```A1, a:a, A2``` are now ```M1, m:m, M2``` I didn't think that would be disrupted by data in the N column.  I will post a new question in a few minutes that shows the issue more clearly.  I will re-factor the example problem to include a text column to the left and right of the quantity column.

Comment: I guess you need to adjust the `arrData = ActiveSheet.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Value` to load M:O. It will be clear after seeing your new post.

Answer (score 0):

[image]this solves your problem according to your description form your first post:[image]

```
Sub ExpandRows()
Dim lastRow As Long
Dim i As Long
Dim qty As Long
Dim productType As String
Dim ws As Worksheet

' Add here your Worksheet name
Set ws = Worksheets("Tabelle1")

' Assuming data starts from row 2
lastRow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

' Loop through each row
For i = lastRow To 2 Step -1
    qty = ws.Cells(i, 1).Value
    productType = ws.Cells(i, 2).Value

    ' Insert rows and fill with product type
    If qty > 1 Then
        Rows(i + 1 & ":" & i + qty - 1).Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
        Range(Cells(i, 2), Cells(i + qty - 1, 2)).Value = productType
    End If
Next i
```

End Sub